# Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost exception : Method not found AddInstance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, asp.net-core

I am trying to do integration tests using Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost which uses the Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting package, and I am getting this error:

> Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddInstance(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
>   !!0)

Under debug its loading `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection\1.0.0-rc2-15877` which is the older version. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
var  _server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseStartup< Foo.FrontEnd.Startup>());
```

my packages :

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
```